# How to show a message after copying is done?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm coding a software in VB2010. So it carrys out a CopyDirectory function but there's nothing which will notify the user of completion. I need something like a message to show up when its done. A progress bar also works. I'm pretty big noob at this.

Answer (score 0):

After copying the file check weather the copied file is there or not. If the file exists, give a message box.

`using System.IO;
    if (File.Exists('path/filename.txt')) 
    {
    Console.WriteLine("file copied successfully");
    }`